# How to wait until the async function is done and then continue the cycle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint, asynchronous

Can you guys help me? I need to wait until the async function is done in cycle and then continue the cycle. I want to get url of attachment file, and then insert it into html.

```js
function getProjects(){
 $.ajax({
      url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items?$orderby=Title asc",
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      },
      success: function (data){
       var items = data.d.results;
       var result = '';
       for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        result += '<tr>';
        result += '<td>'+items[i].Organization+'</td>';
        result += '<td>'+items[i].Title+'</td>';
        result += '<td>'+items[i].Contact+'</td>';
        result += '<td>'+items[i].Description+'</td>';
        result += '<td>'+items[i].Manager+'</td>';
        result += '<td>'+items[i].Participates+'</td>';     
        getAttachments(items[i].Id).done(function(url){
         console.log('1');
        });
                    console.log('2');
        result += '</tr>';

          }
          $('#tableProjects').html(result); 
      },
      error: function (err) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(err));
      }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: If you want to add your result to html after you get the url then put "result += '</tr>';" and "$('#tableProjects').html(result);" inside getAttachments(...).done(function(url){...//Put it here})

Comment: Put your code inside success method. It will run after the async function is complete

Comment: Is it so, that getAttachments function is used for retrieving list item attachments from Projects list?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 Option for you

a) **Use ajax parameter async** ( This approach is not recommend  )

```
   async : false
```

the above parameter will ensure that your browser wait for the call to complete and then it will proceed ahead. The above approach is not good from user point of view , because if you are  uploading a file or the request take long time , then to the user it will appear has the browser has hanged

b) **Write the Complete code in the Success Function** : This is more better approach go through your code, and find the snippet which you want to get executed after ajax call, and paste that in the success callback. This approach seem to bit difficult but once become use to this you approach you will understand the power of async callback's in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Well I would prefer you can go with `$.when` and `.then` as below:

First declare a boolean var inside function

```
function getProjects(){
var valid=false;
$.when(
$.ajax({
            url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items?$orderby=Title asc",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data){
                    dataObtained=data;
                    valid=true;
                }
                $('#tableProjects').html(result);   
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        })).then(function(){
           if(valid)
           {
                var items = dataObtained.d.results;
                var result = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    result += '<tr>';
                    result += '<td>'+items[i].Organization+'</td>';
                    result += '<td>'+items[i].Title+'</td>';
                    result += '<td>'+items[i].Contact+'</td>';
                    result += '<td>'+items[i].Description+'</td>';
                    result += '<td>'+items[i].Manager+'</td>';
                    result += '<td>'+items[i].Participates+'</td>';     
                    getAttachments(items[i].Id).done(function(url){
                        console.log('1');
                    });
                    console.log('2');
                    result += '</tr>';
            }
         });    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it! )))

```js
function uploader(i,items) {
  if( i < items.length ) {
   table += '<tr>';
 table += '<td>'+items[i].Organization+'</td>';
 table += '<td>'+items[i].Title+'</td>';
 table += '<td>'+items[i].Contact+'</td>';
 table += '<td>'+items[i].Description+'</td>';
 table += '<td>'+items[i].Manager+'</td>';
 table += '<td>'+items[i].Participates+'</td>';
 getAttachments(items[i].Id).done(function(url){
  table += '<td>'+url+'</td>';
  table += '</tr>';
  uploader(i+1,items);
 });
  }else{
   $('#tableProjects').html(table);
  }
}

function getProjects(){
 $.ajax({
      url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Projects')/items?$orderby=Title asc",
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      },
      success: function (data){
       var items = data.d.results;
       table="";
          uploader(0,items); 
      },
      error: function (err) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(err));
      }
  }); 
}
```